# Forcing Table Navigation Down Rows Then Across To Next Column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table with X number of rows and at most 5 columns. The user will enter values in Row 1, column 2 then I need to navigate them to Row 2 Column 2 to enter the next value. When they are on the last row for Column 2 then they need to go to row 2 column 3 and so on. They are entering numeric values with a specified number of decimals. Once they enter the appropriate number of decimals I need to force them to the next row/column based on above logic.

[image]

I have set the tabIndex so that it gives me the desired effect. I put my cursor in the first row column 2 and press tab, and it goes down the rows and then over to the next column so pressing the tabKey works:

```
<tr class="calibrateColumns">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="CalCol1" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=51></td>
    <td class="CalCol2" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=52></td>
    <td class="CalCol3" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=53></td>
    <td class="CalCol4" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=54></td>
    <td class="CalCol5" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=55></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="calibrateColumns">
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="CalCol1" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=51></td>
    <td class="CalCol2" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=52></td>
    <td class="CalCol3" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=53></td>
    <td class="CalCol4" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=54></td>
    <td class="CalCol5" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=55></td>
  </tr>
```

I have a function that is checking for the appropriate number of decimals and when they enter that last decimal it makes the current column readonly and then I want to send them to the next available row/column. That is where the problem comes because it is always sending the user to the next column on the same row, so it is navigating horizontally and then vertically down.

Here is my function that is checking for number of entered decimals (input is the object - td  passed into this function):

```
if ((input.html().length - input.html().indexOf(".") - 1) == dec_places) {
      $.tabNext();    //force user to next row.column  using jquery.tabbable plugin              
      input.attr("contenteditable", false);  //set field readonly                 
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of including the jquery.tabbable library which I am currently using and everything navigates horizontally and then vertically instead of what the tabindex specifies. Again, if I just tab through the table (pressing tabKey) then it navigates vertically then horizontally. But if I try and programmatically send them to the next element things go horizontally/vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there exist `next` tr or not if yes then just use `input.closest("tr").next().find("[tabindex=" + tabs + "]").focus()` i.e : to td where tabindex is same and if doesn't exist get the `td[contenteditable=true]:first` tabindex value and use this to put focus on required td.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var dec_places = 2;
$(".calibrateColumns > td[contenteditable]").on("keyup", function() {

  var input = $(this)
  var tabs = input.attr("tabindex") //get tab index
  if ((input.html().length - input.html().indexOf(".") - 1) == dec_places) {

    input.attr("contenteditable", false); //set field readonly 
    //if there is next tr exist
    if (input.closest("tr").next().length) {
      //put focus on td in next tr where tabindex is same
      input.closest("tr").next().find("[tabindex=" + tabs + "]").focus()

    } else {
      //check the conteneditable is true get first one tabindex
      var tab_new = $("table tr:first td[contenteditable=true]:first").attr("tabindex")
      //put foucs thre
      $("table tr:eq(0) td[tabindex=" + tab_new + "]").focus()

    }
  }


})
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="calibrateColumns">
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="CalCol1" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=51></td>
    <td class="CalCol2" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=52></td>
    <td class="CalCol3" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=53></td>
    <td class="CalCol4" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=54></td>
    <td class="CalCol5" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=55></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="calibrateColumns">
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="CalCol1" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=51></td>
    <td class="CalCol2" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=52></td>
    <td class="CalCol3" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=53></td>
    <td class="CalCol4" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=54></td>
    <td class="CalCol5" contenteditable="true" data-val="false" tabindex=55></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks for the quick response and help!